# Oracle - Split the parameter by comma and check if the parameter exist in Column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle and not sure if there are any inbuilt functions to do this task.

I have a column that contains Product_ID's separated by comma.

```
Product_ID
123,234,546,789,487
```

I am passing a list of Product_ID's separated by a comma as varchar2.

so, I am passing "`234,789`" as varchar2.

I want to find if `234` and `789` exist in that column and if exists get that row.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check that **all** the values in your input list are included in the column then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  EXISTS (
  WITH input ( value ) AS (
    SELECT '123,789' FROM DUAL -- Your input value
  )
  SELECT 1
  FROM   input
  WHERE  ','||t.product_id||',' LIKE '%,' || REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL ) || ',%'
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( value, '[^,]+' )
  HAVING COUNT(*) = REGEXP_COUNT( value, '[^,]+' )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Product_ID ) AS
SELECT '123,234,546,789,487' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | PRODUCT_ID          |
> | :------------------ |
> | 123,234,546,789,487 |
> ```

If you want to check that **at least one** value in your input list is in the column then you can use the same query without the line containing the `HAVING` clause.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=21dd303b5f45898a2737ac71954a9644)*

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way - making the comma-separated number lists into JSON arrays so that we can split them using `json_table`, then re-aggregating as nested tables so that we can compare with the `submultiset` operator:

```
create type table_of_pid as table of number;
/

with
  sample_data (product_id) as (
    select '123,234,546,789,487' from dual union all
    select '333,444,555,666,888' from dual
  )
, user_input (product_list) as (
    select '234,789' from dual
  )
select *
from   sample_data
where  ( select cast(collect(pid) as table_of_pid) as input_pid
         from   user_input cross apply
                json_table('[' || product_list || ']', '$[*]'
                           columns pid number path '$')
       )
       submultiset
       ( select cast(collect(pid) as table_of_pid) as input_pid
         from   json_table('[' || product_id || ']', '$[*]'
                           columns pid number path '$')
       )
;

PRODUCT_ID         
-------------------
123,234,546,789,487
```

Your inputs violate First Normal Form, the most basic sanity requirement in a relational database. If the data was in normal form, you wouldn't need any of the JSON trickery. Still, the aggregation into collection and the `submultiset` comparison would be the correct approach even if the data was already in normal form.

Comment: Comma-separated column will not be more than 4 and values I will be at most two. It is not as complicated as you think.

Comment: @Chatra - Do you have a special method for splitting lists of at most 4 values (as opposed to more than that)? I would be very interested in learning such methods. On the other hand, if you don't have such a method, then I don't understand the point you are trying to make. Why is "no more than 4 values" relevant? How does it make it "not as complicated" just because there are at most 4 values, and not 200? (Leaving aside the fact that your own sample data has a list of **5** values!)

Comment: I think I explained it wrong. All I am looking for is if the column value contains one string.

Comment: _"Comma-separated column will not be more than 4 and values I will be at most two. It is not as complicated as you think."_  Doesn't matter.  The fact that you have _any_ comma-separated values in a single column violates the first rule of relational data design - First Normal Form.  Get your data model correct - design all tables to Third Normal Form - and your matching problem becomes trivial.

Comment: @Chatra - the solution you marked as "correct answer" does **exactly** the same thing as my solution. So, if you "explained it wrong", then how is that answer "correct"? More likely, you are clueless. Be well!

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to store comma-separated values into a single column.

One option to do what you asked for is in the following example; read comments within code. Note that - for large tables - performance WILL suffer.

```
SQL> set ver off
SQL>
SQL> with
  2  test (product_id) as
  3    -- your sample table
  4    (select '123,234,546,789,487' from dual union all
  5     select '111,222,333'         from dual
  6    ),
  7  test_split as
  8    -- you have to split it into rows
  9    (select product_id,
 10            regexp_substr(product_id, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) val
 11     from test
 12     cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 13                                    connect by level <= regexp_count(product_id, ',') + 1
 14                                   ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 15    ),
 16  parameter_split as
 17    -- split input parameter into rows as well
 18    (select regexp_substr('&&par_id', '[^,]+', 1, level) val
 19     from dual
 20     connect by level <= regexp_count('&&par_id', ',') + 1
 21    )
 22  -- join split values, return the result
 23  select distinct t.product_id
 24  from test_split t join parameter_split p on p.val = t.val;
Enter value for par_id: 123,546

PRODUCT_ID
-------------------
123,234,546,789,487

SQL> undefine par_id
SQL> /
Enter value for par_id: 333

PRODUCT_ID
-------------------
111,222,333

SQL>
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, your query checks whether `PRODUCT_ID` contains 123 **or** 546, rather than 123 **and** 546 as the OP requested.